# Beginner java Q about using for loop, if statement and while loop

Tags: java

```
Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);                                        
System.out.println("enter number");                                     
int no = userIn.nextInt();                                      
while (no > 20)                                     
{                                       
  System.out.println("too big");                                        
  no = userIn.nextInt();                                        
  {                                     
    if (no <= 20)                                       
    {                                       
      for (int i=0; i < no; i++)                                        
      {                                     
        System.out.println(i+1);                                        
      }                                     
    }                                       
  }                                     
}
```

I am sorry to ask such a silly question, but I am starting to learn programming and I can't put my head around tutorials. I am trying to code where if a given input if larger than 20, it will give the output of "too big" and ask you to enter a number again until it is 20 or less. If the number is 20 or less, it will count from 1 to the chosen number from keyboard. Why does this only work when I enter a number that is large than 20 and after, but not straight away after compiling, is it wrong position, may I ask how I can resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have another block after `no = userIn.nextInt();`? End the loop there. Your `if` is a bad idea in the `while` loop.

Comment: I'd also consider using a `do {...} while (no > 20);` instead and prompt the user from within the loop

Comment: I wanted it to ask me the same question again if the input was larger than 20, if I remove that, it doesn't repeat. Oh right I see, what loop would be best if I may ask?

Answer (score 2):

Simply putting if your number(`no`) is less than 20, You  will never get inside the while loop. Hence it will never execute your `for` loop inside the `while` loop.

do it something like this

```
Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);                                        
System.out.println("enter number");                                     
int no = userIn.nextInt();                                      
while (no > 20)                                     
{                                       
  System.out.println("too big");                                        
  no = userIn.nextInt();                           
}
 for (int i=0; i < no; i++)                                        
      {                                     
        System.out.println(i+1);                                        
      }
```

Comment: Oh I see now, because the for loop is out of the while loop, it can now execute beforehand lol opps, thank you Yohannes :)

Comment: you welcome. accept it if you find it helpful.

Comment: just out of curiosity, do I have to use a do while to have the opposite effect? meaning, if I enter a number less than 21, it will count from 1 to the number and ask again, until a number larger than 20 is inputted which will end the program?

Comment: I can't see that is possible. Do while loop is like while loop. the only difference is do while executed at least once regardless how the logic control evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

you can read infinity till the user enter a number less than 20

```
 Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter number");
            int no;
            while ((no = userIn.nextInt()) > 20) {
                System.out.println("too big");
             // the while loop will stop when a number less than 20 is entered
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + 1);
            }
```

**TEST:**
[image]